# Angular 2 key listener events not triggering

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have done the session timed out functionality using angular 2. But i need to reset the flag when the user is in active state. but the key listeners are not working properly.

The **'handleTimeOut()'** function not calling when the **key press** or **key down** happened.

```
 @Component({
     templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
     directives: [LoadingModal],
     host: {
      '(document:keypress, document:keydown)': 'handleTimeOut($event)'
     }
    })
    class ConferenceApp {
      idleTime: any;
      constructor(
       public events: Events       
     ){
       platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.idleTime = 0;
        setInterval(() => {
         this.idleTime = this.idleTime+1;
         //3 mintues
         if(this.idleTime > 4){              
           this.events.publish('appclose:presented', 'Session Timed Out', "Your session has timed out, Please close the app.");
         }
       }, 60*1000);        
    });
   }

    handleTimeOut(event){           
        console.log('inside handle timed out');
        this.idleTime = 0;
      }
    }
```